# Count rows of a matrix and give back an array

Tags: matlab, matrix, count, output, rows

I would like to know how to count rows in an matrix in such a way that gives an output for each colum. for example:

```
X=[1 1 1;
   5 5 5]
```

I would like to find a command that when I input the matrix X the answers is [2 2 2], so that it counts the number of rows per column.

I have already found nunel(X) but the answer is a scalar numel(X)=6, whereas I need per column.

Comment: `size(X,1)` will give you the number of rows *in the matrix* (a scalar). a matrix has only **one** number of rows, i.e. each column has the same number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

`size(X,1)` will give you the number of rows *in the matrix* (a scalar). a matrix has only *one* number of rows, i.e. each column has the same number of rows.

however if you still want the number of rows per each column you can use:

```
X = [1 1 1;
    5 5 5];
nrows = size(X,1);
ncols = size(X,2);
nrowsPerCol = repmat(nrows, [1 ncols]) % [2 2 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Each matrix object in MATLAB has height and width property. 
In other words: each column has the same number of rows.

To get this value, use MATLAB's [size](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) function:

```
[numOfRows, numOfCols] = size(X);
```